# Missing return type on a function which returns a React Fragment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am currently trying to clean up some ESLint warnings on my project, and I am stuck on a missing return type on the following function. I have tried to set the return type to `React.ReactFragment`, however that gives me an error on all areas where the function is called.

```
export const RightsTooltip = () =>
  <>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet.</p>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet.</p>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet./p>
  </>
```

Usage of the function:

```
<Group>
  <b>Additional rights</b>
  <Hint tooltip={<RightsTooltip/>}/>
</Group>
```

Error when return type is set to `React.ReactFragment`:

```
'RightsTooltip' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactFragment' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

Comment: `export const RightsTooltip = (): React.ReactElement => {`

Comment: Try wrapping the react fragment with paranthesis `( )`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A React functional component should *always* return a `JSX.Element`. That's the type you want if you are requiring that all functional components have an explicit return type

```
export const RightsTooltip = (): JSX.Element =>
  <>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet.</p>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet.</p>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet.</p>
  </>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=6#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWONCAOwGd4FgBzACxiYBUIIAGxjAwcALxwAFAEoAXHABSAZQAaAOgCigpCCQN44gHyk4cADwmzZ82CPmWOBuyMAZaLriimAVxDmAekdGFzgAEyFoOCZgeBQ9GAAaOkYmJAwkGB8oOBQw0WAmNGBnOCRBWPU4AFkUbMK4QRQPTPVAu1NrW3tg5zcPPG8-QN7QiMEomLiE5PpmdJhM7Nz8sELi0vLKmrqoBqaWmDaAjusLOwcYJxd3IkGwX38gq5CjcMicqdyZlPmMrJyeQKRRK7DKFSOO3qTEazSIrXaVgsARMpDmLDgiwxknMbC4PH4QhEYhRQA)